# row_number and orderby window function narrow transformation equivalent in spark

Tags: apache-spark

```
df.withColumn("col1", functions.row_number().over(Window.partitionBy("col2").orderBy("col3")));
```

This operation I think is a wide transformation in nature where it will sort and partition and for every partition together. Due to which a lot of shuffling is occurring and causing performance issues.

I have a use case where data in each partition is independent of other partitions. So I want to run the above row number function for each partition only i.e I need a narrow transformation and I couldn't find a way to do it.

- Is there a way to achieve it ?
- I read orderBy vs sort methods which are wide and narrow respectively. Does that hold true in this case also?

Comment: your `row_number()` window will first partition the data and then sort on the key within the partition. I think this is exactly what you require.

Comment: By partition, I mean data frame partitions. So I am reading data from Kafka and in Kafka data order is maintained per partition. Each partition of Kafka will have a corresponding partition in the data frame while reading from it. But since the data frame is the same the window partition will shuffle existing partitions to make new windows. What I want is to make windows on top of existing partitions. I hope this clarifies the requirement

Comment: have you looked into `foreachPartition()` -- [link](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.foreachPartition.html)